# Extracting rows values using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a gridview that has multiple rows. I am trying to iterate through each row get values and submit the values to database using ajax class.

The html from gridview for one row is

```
 <input id="GridView3_ctl03_chkEmployee" type="checkbox" name="$GridView3$ctl03$chkEmployee" />
            </td><td>
                        <span id="_GridView3_ctl03_lblprivateId" class="idName">6878</span>
                    </td><td>
                        <span id="_GridView3_ctl03_lblCompany" class="FName">abcd Inc.</span>
                    </td>
        </tr><tr style="color:#8C4510;background-color:#FFF7E7;">
            <td>
```

I have following jquery code that selects each row that has been checked.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
           $("#submit").click(function () {
               var record;
               alert("starting");
               $("#<%=GridView3.ClientID%> input[id*='chkEmployee']:checked").each(function () {
                   var value = $(this).find('.FName').val();
                   alert(value);
               });
           });
       });
```

I cant extract the values for both FName and idName. I get error undefined. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: can you post you HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there are multiple classes you will need to try something like this

```
var arr = [];
  $('.yourClassName').each(function(){
      arr.push($(this).text());
   });
```

In this, array will have your values and you can exploit it as you like

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var arr = [];
 $('tr [type="checkbox"]:checked').parent().each(function () {
   var value = $(this).find('.FName').val();
   arr.push(value);   
});
  callAjaxGetJoiningDate(arr);
});
function callAjaxGetJoiningDate(hashVal) {
var address = "Ypurpage.aspx";
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: address,
    data: { empCode: hashVal },
    beforeSend: function () {
        // this is where we append a loading image
        $('#ajax-panel').html('<div class="loading"><img src="images/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." /></div>');
    },
    success: function (data) {
        // successful request; do something with the data
        $('#ajax-panel').empty();
        var actualData = data.trim().split('~');
        $("#YourResultControl").val(actualData[1]);

    },
    error: function () {
        // failed request; give feedback to user
        $('#ajax-panel').html('<p class="error"><strong>Oops!</strong> Try that again in a few moments.</p>');
    }
});
```